# fatal error in launching google map sample in android

Tags: android, google-maps

i am trying to run a sample from a following link 
[commonsguy](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk/)
but getting following run time error in logcat

```
   06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782):     at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782):     at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:209)
06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:203)
06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-13 13:01:45.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(782):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's on this line 
com.commonsware.android.maps.NooYawk.<init>(NooYawk.java:37)?

Comment: Sorry , i have updated the error please go through it

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, that your manifest contains this line:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

It must be the child of the application tag. For me it helped.